# Jquery: Animating height

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Okay, so im still having some problems with my animating element.
I got some help earlier, and i almost got it, but i still got one problem.
I tried finding a solution, but i can't find anything.

When i click the first line, it animates the first line.
When i click the second line, it animates the first & second line.
When i click the third line, it animates the first, second & third and so on.

I want it to animate only the one that belongs to the line. Not all of them at once.

My script looks like this:

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() { $("#new_user").live("click", function() { $(this).children(".new_users_box").animate({opacity: 'toggle' }); }); }); </script>
```

And my html / php code like this:

```
    <div id="new_memb_content" class="box_square">
    <img src="mysite/resources/newest-members.png" width="245" height="27" style="margin-left:-8px;" /><br><br>
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['username'])
        {
            include 'db_connect.php';
            $sql = "SELECT username, id, gender, user_thumb1 FROM members ORDER BY members.`id` DESC LIMIT 20";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $thumb1 = $row['user_thumb1'];
                $new_id = $row['id'];
                $new_user = $row['username'];

                echo '
                <div id="new_user">
                <a class="box_round" style="background-color:#101010 !important;">'.$new_user.'</a>
                <div class="box_newest new_users_box"><br>
                <a href="mysite/user.php?id='.$new_id.'"><img class="new_user_thumb" src="'.$thumb1.'" /></a>
                </div>
                ';
            }
        }

        else 
        header("location:mysite");
        ?>
        </div>
```

What am i still doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick remarks:

For every user found in your database, your script will echo the following div with the needed information:

```
<div id="new_user">
                <a class="box_round" style="background-color:#101010 !important;">'.$new_user.'</a>
                <div class="box_newest new_users_box"><br>
                <a href="mysite/user.php?id='.$new_id.'"><img class="new_user_thumb" src="'.$thumb1.'" /></a>
                </div>
```

Your div #new_user will be produced for every user returned from the database. ID's are to be unique so it's best to add a suffix to ID's when they are declared in while loops. An idea is to implement a counter within the while loop to add to the div's ID.

I'm not sure if identical IDs are dismissed or they are still functional, but fixing this would be your first step. Seems like your script is animating on every #new_user div.

Answer (score 1):

you are using same ID `new_user` for all the user container. id is unique attribute and this code is violating html structure. just use class instead of id here.

http://jsfiddle.net/QswrL/